# How to change limits of this integral to new ones

Tags: definite-integrals

I wanna to change the limits of the following integral from $(0,0.6)$ to (-1,1), How can I do this?
$$\int_0^{0.6} r^k e^{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{c_n r^n}{(1+g*r)^{N-3}}}dr$$

Comment: What are you integrating with respect to?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why do you want to do that ? It helps in no way to compute the integral.

Comment: I want to change the limits so that I can apply two point Gaussian quadrature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate variable change is obtained by equation of line of two points namely $(0,0.6)$ and $(-1,1)$ so I get
$$y=\frac 2 {0.6}x -1 \tag{1}$$ and then $x$ is obtained $$x=\frac {(y+1) 0.6}2\tag{2}$$ and $$dx=0.3 \;dy \tag{3}$$ So if I set $y=-1$ I get $x=0$ and if $y=1$ I get $x=0.6$.

So by substitution of (2) and  (3) in the main integral we can obtain the desire integral with desire limits.